# How to call our own qnamakerservice with appinsights

Tags: botframework

How to use qnamakerservice of our own to track logs using appinsights instead of using the below in the sample code which was given in 'qna-with-appinsights' example?

```
// Call QnAMaker.generateAnswer to retrieve possible Question and Answer pairings for the user's message.
const results = await super.generateAnswer(turnContext.activity.text, top, scoreThreshold);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to use a different QnA Maker Knowledge Base that you've built yourself already instead of the one that gets created by the `bot.recipe` when you run the `msbot clone` command?

You would just need to change the `qnaEndpointSettings` in `index.js` LN 53.

```js
    const qnaEndpointSettings = {
        knowledgeBaseId: qnaConfig.kbId,
        endpointKey: qnaConfig.endpointKey,
        host: qnaConfig.hostname
    };
```

These values are populated from your `.bot` file, so make sure you add your custom QnAMaker credentials there.

This could be done either by

1. adding them to your `.bot` file manually. So in the particular sample you're using you would edit the object of `"type: "qna"`:

   ```
   {
       "type": "qna",
       "name": "qna-with-insights-QnAMaker",
       "id": "34",
       "kbId": "",
       "subscriptionKey": "",
       "endpointKey": "",
       "hostname": ""
   }
   ```

OR

2. use the `msbot connect qna ...` command, which would make sure that you have a properly formatted qna object. [Documentation here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/MSBot/docs/add-services.md).